# Migrate Running Journey from one SFMC to another SFMC (Sales Force Marketing Cloud)

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, migration, package-manager

I want to migrate a running journey from one SFMC instance to another SFMC instance.

So I have paused the running journey and migrated the journey through the package manager.

After migration, the Journey has deployed in Draft mode. There is no option available to resume the paused journey but only to activate the journey.

I want to Resume or Start the Journey from the same state as when I paused the Journey.

Anyone can help me with this ???

[image: Paused Journey in one SFMC Instance]

[image: Same Paused Journey after Migrated to another SFMC Instance]

Comment: what do you mean same state? you need to activate the journey in the new BU

Comment: @Abhishek - remember to mark my answer as accepted if it has been helpful

Answer (score 1):

This is simply not possible. A copied journey is just a collection of assets on a journey canvas. You also need underlying data, and much more to make it work. Also, you can't assume you can just take a "snapshot" of your journey with all contacts within, complete with their individual states. As EazyE states in his comment, you need to activate the journey wherever you copy it to, and ensure the contacts are being injected according to the entry source defined there. All contacts will enter from the beginning and proceed according to their data and your journey paths.